# How to hand over different objects to a Method

Tags: c#, object

I like to do something like this but have no idea how to solve it.
Let's say I have different classes programmed against and Interface:

```
public class A : IMyInterface
{
    public string name = "NameOfA";
    public string description = "descriptiontextA";
}
public class B : IMyInterface
{
    public string name = "NameOfB";
    public string description = "descriptiontextB";
}

public class programm 
{
    void DoSmthSpecial(var class) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"This is {class.name}");    
    }
}
```

Where var class should be class A or class B.
So basically I am calling similar methods for different classes. Can someone help here?

Comment: `DoSmthSpecial(IMyInterface myclass)`? Though currently your classes have fields, not properties, so they probably don't conform to your interface.

Comment: What is `IMyInterface`? Neither class actually implements any interface members.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your interface should define any common properties:

```cs
public interface IMyInterface
{
    string Name {get;}
    string Description {get;}
}
```

Which are then implemented by your classes:

```cs
public class A : IMyInterface
{
    public string Name {get;} = "NameOfA";
    public string Description {get;} = "descriptiontextA";
}
public class B : IMyInterface
{
    public string Name {get;} = "NameOfB";
    public string Description {get;} = "descriptiontextB";
}
```

And now your `DoSmthSpecial` method can make use of this interface:

```cs
void DoSmthSpecial(IMyInterface myClass) 
{
    Console.WriteLine($"This is {myClass.Name}");    
}
```

You can call it like this:

```cs
IMyInterface myInst = new A();
DoSmthSpecial(myInst);
```

Or like this:

```cs
A myInst = new A();
DoSmthSpecial(myInst);
```

[Try it online](https://rextester.com/RITTG30875)

Answer (score 3):

The idea of an interface is it states the shape of some implementing class to code that wants to interact with objects that have a specific shape/capable of behaving in some general way, but aren't bothered about what the implementing class actually does. This can take the form of properties and methods

```
public interface IMyInterface{
   string Name {get;set;}

   string GetSomethingCool();
}

public class A : IMyInterface
{
    public string Name {get;set;} = "NameOfA";

    public string GetSomethingCool() => "SomethingCool";
}

public class B : IMyInterface
{
    public string Name {get;set;} ;

    public string GetSomethingCool() => "S" + "OMETHING".ToLower() + string.Concat(new[] {'C', 'o', 'o', 'l' });

    public B(){
        Name = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    }
}

public class Program
{
    static void DoSmthSpecial(IMyInterface x) 
    {
        //here you can use anything that is available on IMyInterface, property or method
        Console.WriteLine(x.GetSomethingCool());

        Console.WriteLine(x.Name);

        //avoid the temptation to inspect the type of x and do subclass specific stuff
        if(x is A a) 
            a.SomethingOnlyOnA();    //avoid
    }

    static void Main(){

        //can pass an A or a B in as something that validly implements IMyInterface
        DoSmthSpecial(new A()); 
        DoSmthSpecial(new B()); 
       
    }
}
```

The two classes have very different approaches to returning the same string from the `GetSomethingCool()` method, and different strategies for setting the Name property - the calling code doesn't know or care how the value is generated; it just knows from the interface that there is a method/property with some name it can call and get/set the data/perform the actions of the method.

Comment: Personally, I would make the setter functions private, or not have them at all!

Comment: OK, but it's more likely that the OP should define `Name` as an interface property.

Answer (score -2):

Use Generics like this

```
void DoSmthSpecial<T>(T class) 
{
    // your code here    
}
```

And call this method like this.

```
B objB = new B();
DoSmthSpecial<B>(objB);
```

Comment: Er.. No; there's no need for generics

Comment: Without a constraint on `T`, the `DoSmthSpecial` method is restricted in what it can do with its parameter arguments, unless you want to resort to runtime type-checking.

Comment: Definitely agree with Caius, using generics will likely generate code for each type used to instantiate the function. A common base interface will work much more efficently and be a bit easier to understand.